# How to have an application closed on lid close in OS X

Tags: macos, lid

I have a MacBook Air. I often use Microsoft's RDP client to connect to a virtual workstation. I need this RDP session to be automatically closed (quit RDP) when I close the lid, before OS X goes to sleep.

How can this functionality be achieved?

Comment: What is the OS X application you're using to connect to the windows box?  Are you using http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client ?

Comment: Yes, Remote Desktop Client from Microsoft.

Comment: You *might* want to ask this question at the http://apple.stackexchange.com/ site.  Tho someone here may know, I'd envision needing to create a custom sleep script for this which checks for the RDP program and closes it.  What you're trying to accomplish is the opposite of what Sleep was intended for.

Comment: @Colyn1337 OS X questions are on topic here. Please do not advise users to post their question elsewhere, as cross-posting is not allowed. Maxim can have the question *migrated* to Ask Different if it does not get a suitable answer within, say, a couple of days. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @slhck I never said it wasn't.  I was simply recommending a more specific community.

Comment: Why specifically does it need to disconnect before sleeping? The server will automatically disconnect it when it detects the connection has dropped, and the client will re-establish the connection when your mac wakes up.

Comment: @Colyn1337 Just keep in mind that while that's a more specific community, there are also less people there; Also, communities themselves are not segregated-- I'm sure many people browse both Ask Different and SuperUser, if not the majority of them.

Comment: @DartAndroid, the situation is that I am not sure who will be around the laptop when I wakes up from sleep. What if it's the people who will be willing to find something that is really on a remote RDP-access machine. With RDP dropped on lid action, I am sure in such case people won't even know I was using RDP at first glance. I know this may sound strange, but that is a real world scenario I need to be prepared for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a couple of tools that allow you to intercept OS X' power status changes:

- [Scenario](http://www.lagentesoft.com/scenario/index.html) and [Power Manager](http://www.dssw.co.uk/powermanager/standard/index.html?utm_source=dssw&utm_medium=blog&utm_campaign=how-to), both commercial and GUI tools.
- [Sleep Watcher](http://www.bernhard-baehr.de/), free and open source, but command line.

#### Sleep Watcher installation

Let's try this with Sleep Watcher. Download the tool from Bernhard Baehr's homepage and follow the installation instructions: assuming you unpacked the download to your Desktop, call the following commands from a Terminal window:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/share/man/man8
sudo cp ~/Desktop/sleepwatcher_2.2.1/sleepwatcher /usr/local/sbin
sudo cp ~/Desktop/sleepwatcher_2.2.1/sleepwatcher.8 /usr/local/share/man/man8
```

This will install the `sleepwatcher` binary and the manpages. You will be prompted for an administrator password.

#### Creating a sleep script

Now, let's create a sleep script called `~/.sleep`. It will contain the commands that are run when the machine is put to sleep (i.e. when the lid closes).

```
touch ~/.sleep
open -e !$
```

In this file, add the following:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Remote Desktop Connection" to quit'
```

This will quit the Microsoft RDP application through AppleScript commands. You can do this with any application as long as you change the name according to its title. Save the file. Now we need to make it executable:

```
chmod +x ~/.sleep
```

#### Testing the sleep script

Now test your script by first starting the RDP program, then running the following in Terminal:

```
/usr/local/sbin/sleepwatcher --verbose --sleep ~/.sleep
```

This will not output anything, so leave both RDP and the Sleep Watcher running, then close the lid of your MacBook. Wait a couple of seconds until it really goes to sleep. Then wake it up again. Did RDP close? Great! Did something go wrong? Look at the output of the `sleepwatcher` command to get a hint about where it failed.

You can now cancel the Sleep Watcher by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> in Terminal.

#### Running the script in background

In order to have the Sleep Watcher run at all times, you need to make it a LaunchDaemon. Create a new configuration file by copying the example configuration and `rc`-scripts.

```
sudo cp ~/Desktop/sleepwatcher_2.2.1/config/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher-20compatibility.plist /Library/LaunchDaemons/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher.plist
sudo cp ~/Desktop/sleepwatcher_2.2.1/config/rc.* /etc
```

Now load the configuration files with `launchd`:

```
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/de.bernhard-baehr.sleepwatcher.plist
```

That's all you need. Now the `.sleep` file will always be executed whenever you sleep your Mac.

Comment: Since the time this marvelous answer was provided, Microsoft has changed the name of it's application, so the correct osascript call is now this: `osascript -e 'tell application "Remote Desktop Connection" to quit'`

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov Thanks for the comment, but isn't this what my answer already says?

Comment: My bad, probably I had something different, and you initially povided a correct naming. I am now calling two osascripts by the way. One to close Microsoft Remote Desktop, and the other one to close actual session windows which go by the name "Remote Desktop Connection".